# JSPDF: Adding images as header and Footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

HI I am trying to add a header and footer image to my pdf. But nothing is showing up.

Here's a plnkr for the same.

https://plnkr.co/edit/okwxsY6IuDlKLMxOtUd8

```
  doc.fromHTML($('#content').get(0), 15, 15, {
          'width': 250,
          'margin': 1,
          'pagesplit': true,
          'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
```

Can someone please drop in some light and help?

Answer (score 0):

According to what i know is you can add multiple times html using doc.addHTML so by that you can first add header part then body then footer, but also if #content part contains header and footer it shall show that on the generated file